# Getting input from user till he enters a number

Tags: c++, char, int

I have to get character input from user till he enters a number. I also need the number user entered last.

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fun() {
    char c;
    while(1) {
        if(cin>>c == 1) {  //To check if we are still getting input
            if(isdigit(c)) { //If a number is found return to the main function
                return c-48;  //Char converted to Int
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return c-48;
}

int main() {
    int a = fun();
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Now for input like `ahd qer 12 32` it gives output as `1` which I know it would give. What I want for output is `12`. How to do that? You can do some change in main function too. I ultimately want the number stored in the variable `a`.

**SOLUTION**

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int fun() {
        string c;
        while(cin>>c) {
            if(isdigit(c[0]))
                return stoi(c);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int a = fun();
        cout<<a<<" ";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Gyanshu What about special characters (e.g. `#`/`$`/etc..)? Why aren't you, at least, using `isdigit` if you want to know if the character represents a digit?

Comment: At least in C passing a (signed) char to `isdigit` is undefined behavior (and you need an `#include <ctype.h>`).

Comment: Ok i would replace it with `isdigit`. But that also gives me only the first digit of the number. Is there a way to get the whole number?

Comment: `c` is potentially uninitialized at the end of `fun`.

Comment: With input like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, I would keep a running sum starting with 0.  For each new digit, multiply the sum by 10 and add the new digit --> 123.

Comment: Off topic: You may find replacing `return c-48;` with `return c-'0';` makes your code easier to read.

Comment: @Gyanshu So don't read single character at the time? Read in bulk, and do your processing afterwards.

Comment: @chux But I don't know the length of number beforehand.

Comment: @chux Taking into the account the sample input/output, your solution would return `1232`, while OP wants `12`.

Comment: @Gyanshu By writing some code, obviously. I gave you a hint. Whether you want to use it, or not - it's up to you.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `sum = 0; sum = sum*10 + 1; sum = sum*10 + 2; sum = sum*10 + 3;` --> `sum = 123`.  OP just needs to put this in a loop.

Comment: @chux Please look at OPs sample input, and expected output. You neglected to look at it, even after I mentioned it.

Comment: @Gyanshu It's not only a single line. Your question reads as: _I tried to solve this task, by writing this piece of code, which doesn't do what I want, but I am too lazy to think of a way to fix it, please do it for me_. That's why _I_ downvoted - the lack of research.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Are you talking about taking input as string? Then how would I recognise when I get a number?

Comment: For each line, ask yourself, "What does this do?" Then ask "Does this make sense in the context of what I need to do?" For example, what does `return c-48;` do?

Comment: It converts the character to an integer because value of '0' is 48.

Comment: Correct (with caveats you are not likely to encounter any time soon). How large of a number can it produce?

Comment: @Gyanshu The way you are doing it currently? `std::find_if (str.begin (), str.end (), [] (const char c) {return isdigit (c);});` returns iterator to the first digit, in a given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!
Credit : @AlgirdasPreidžius

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int fun() {
        string c;
        while(cin>>c) {
            if(isdigit(c[0]))
                return stoi(c);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int a = fun();
        cout<<a<<" ";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: My inputs do not contains strings like these.

Comment: It only contains either digits or strings

Comment: Moreover for the input you stated I would scan the whole string.